# Using boost::split brings up a load of weird errors

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <string>
#include "boost\date_time\gregorian\gregorian.hpp"
#include <boost\algorithm\string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost;


void printString()
{
vector<string> strs;
boost::split(strs, "string to split", boost::is_any_of(' '));
cout << strs[0];
}
```

This flags up about 6 errors in Boost and 1 in std. My thinking is the namespaces are messing up. This is an edited version of the actual code base but basically I'm using boost::gregorian for a seperate date_time thing and boost for the algoritm code base. I saw an example and using more than one namespace was fine. For me it's just not letting me use split.

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a single character to `boost::is_any_of`, but it expects a sequence.

Change the code from:
from: `boost::is_any_of(' ')`
to:   `boost::is_any_of(" ")` and you should be golden.

(oh yeah, and add `#include <vector>` and `#include <iostream>` to your example.

Comment: Thanks. And also it didn't like me using the two namespaces so instead I used the boost namespace but weirdly enough I still have to have boost::split still or otherwise it crashes.