# boost split method results in iterator error

Tags: c++, boost

> \libraries\boost_1_57_0\boost\range\iterator.hpp(69): error C2039:
>   'type' : is not a member of
>   'boost::mpl::eval_if_c,boost::range_mutable_iterator>'

My code

```
std::vector<std::string> strs;
std::string line="test a string";
boost::split(strs, line, boost::is_any_of(' '));
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491998/using-boostsplit-brings-up-a-load-of-weird-errors/27492706#27492706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::is_any_of` takes a sequence (e.g. a string), not a single element (e.g. a char). The functor it produces returns true on a match with any one of the elements in the passed sequence.

```
boost::split(strs, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));
//                                        ^ ^
//                                   Double quotes
```

Comment: Thank you but then I still get this error
`vc\include\xutility(2132): error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'`

Comment: @loggeruser: Did you read that error message and follow its advice? It's written in fairly plain English.

Comment: Yes, but I don't test my code with VS alone, I need it to work with Unix too, how can I eliminate this error in VS without #define'ing anything ?

Comment: You have to use different compiler options anyway with different compilers. Just pass the `/D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` option when you compile on VS.